# jar launched as .exe Exceptions when setting path to "java.home" using Javas .getStandardFileManager

Tags: java, compilation, launch4j

[EDIT:] After trying to run the .jar with a batch script i found that

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, Locale.getDefault(), null);
```

still causes a NullpointerException. So setting "java.home" doesn't seem to work that way when the program is run from an exe, no matter if it's wrapped or started from a batch script. 
Anyone knows a workaround?
[/EDIT]

I got a program where the user can import java code which will be compiled at runtime. To use the JavaCompiler, the property of java.home needs to be set to the installed JDK:

```
System.setProperty("java.home", [USER-ENTERED-PATH-TO-JDK);
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
...
```

This works fine when the program is started as JAR. However i wrap it for deployment with launch4j to an .exe. If the user sets the path to "java.home" (which would be e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91) in the .exe, the following exception occures:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\lib\tzdb.dat 
at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile$1.run(ZoneInfoFile.java:261)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile.<clinit>(ZoneInfoFile.java:251)
at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo.getTimeZone(ZoneInfo.java:589)
at java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.java:560)
at java.util.TimeZone.setDefaultZone(TimeZone.java:666)
at java.util.TimeZone.getDefaultRef(TimeZone.java:636)
at java.util.Date.normalize(Date.java:1197)
at java.util.Date.toString(Date.java:1030)
at java.util.Properties.store0(Properties.java:829)
at java.util.Properties.store(Properties.java:818)
at GenericTool.Config.writeConfig(Config.java:192)
at GUI.MainWindow$20.actionPerformed(MainWindow.java:1211)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\lib\tzdb.dat 
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile$1.run(ZoneInfoFile.java:255)
... 50 more


can't open C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\lib\tzmappings.
```

It seems like the JDK is not recognised when setting the path to java.home so no functionity of the program works anymore and it has to be restarted. Doing the same when executing the program as a jar causes no problems.
Anyone knows a solution for that?

Comment: Could it be that the space in the name is causing the exception?

Comment: You mean the space in Program Files? If i remove it i get a NullpointerException when trying to compile code with the program. And i still get the same exception as stated abpve in addition. It seems like setting "java.home" in the .exe totally messes the program up.